# ORA-00933 while trying to run the below update query in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, ora-00933

I have the below query which works fine when run in SQL Server.
But the same is failing in Oracle db.

Do I need to rewrite the query. Any solutions on how to proceed?

```
UPDATE SFFM SET
SFFM.INTSTRTDTE = SCCS.INTSTRTDTE, 
SFFM.INTENDDTE = SCCS.INTENDDTE,    
SFFM.EFFDATE = SCCS.INTSTRTDTE      
FROM SCCS
WHERE SFFM.SECID = 'TEST1'      
AND SFFM.SECID = SCCS.SECID     
AND SFFM.SEQ = SCCS.SEQ 
AND SFFM.AMENDDATE IS NULL
```

Error is:

```
Error at Command Line:7 Column:1 Error report: SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MERGE INTO SFFM 
USING 
(
  SELECT SCCS.INTSTRTDTE, 
  SCCS.INTENDDTE,    
  SCCS.EFFDATE      
  FROM SCCS
  WHERE SCCS.SECID = 'TEST1'        
  AND SCCS.AMENDDATE IS NULL
) ta ON (ta.SECID = SFFM.SECID AND SFFM.SEQ = ta.SEQ )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
    SET SFFM.INTSTRTDTE = ta.INTSTRTDTE, 
    SFFM.INTENDDTE = ta.INTENDDTE,    
    SFFM.EFFDATE = ta.INTSTRTDTE
```

Comment: would this merge query work in SQL as well as sybase?

Answer (score 0):

You can't write such select. In case of update you need to write subselect if you need to query data from other table:

```
UPDATE SFFM
   SET (SFFM.INTSTRTDTE, SFFM.INTENDDTE, SFFM.EFFDATE) =
       (SELECT SCCS.INTSTRTDTE,
               SCCS.INTENDDTE,
               SCCS.INTSTRTDTE
          FROM SCCS
         WHERE SFFM.SECID = 'TEST1'
           AND SFFM.SECID = SCCS.SECID
           AND SFFM.SEQ = SCCS.SEQ
           AND SFFM.AMENDDATE IS NULL)
```

Comment: hi, the query is not working. Error is: Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: sorry, had some typos in `SELECT` part

Comment: #Janis Baiza: are you gonna give the correct version of the same.

Comment: Updated query gives: SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Thats mean you have more than one corresponding row in `SCCS`. Either add additional conditions to get only one row or, if there are multiple lines with equal values, add `DISTINCT` keyword after `SELECT`

Comment: the select query fetches three rows with three columns which while updating to SFFM fails.

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Because you have a syntax error in your update statement. You cannot do that in Oracle, neither can you directly join the tables in an update statement.

For a verbose solution, you could use **MERGE**:

```
MERGE INTO SFFM f 
USING(
SELECT INTSTRTDTE, INTENDDTE, INTSTRTDTE, SEQ
FROM SCCS
) c 
ON (f.SECID = c.SECID AND f.SEQ = c.SEQ)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET f.INTSTRTDTE = c.INTSTRTDTE,
    f.INTENDDTE    = c.INTENDDTE,
    f.EFFDATE      = c.INTSTRTDTE
  WHERE f.SECID    = 'TEST1'
  AND f.AMENDDATE IS NULL;
```

Comment: SELECT still giving the same error, invalid identifier

Comment: Error at Command Line:44 Column:62
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "SCCS"."EFFDATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: But there is no `SCCS"."EFFDATE` in your posted code. EFFDATE is a column in `SFFM ` table. Have you posted the correct table and column names? Can you correct the name and try the updated query `MERGE INTO SFFM f 
USING(
SELECT SCCS.INTSTRTDTE INTSTRTDTE, SCCS.INTENDDTE INTENDDTE, SCCS.INTSTRTDTE INTSTRTDTE
FROM SCCS
) c 
ON (f.SECID = c.SECID AND f.SEQ = c.SEQ)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET f.INTSTRTDTE = c.INTSTRTDTE,
    f.INTENDDTE    = c.INTENDDTE,
    f.EFFDATE      = c.INTSTRTDTE
  WHERE f.SECID    = 'TEST1'
  AND f.AMENDDATE IS NULL;`

Comment: #Lalit: yes, it was a typo from my side. while running the given query by you, i am getting Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "C"."SEQ": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @user3346282 Yes, since SEQ is not selected in the USING clause. I have fixed it in the query above. Can you try now. Should work now.

Comment: After correcting the query, Error is: SQL Error: ORA-00904: "F"."SEQ": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Do you have any column named SEQ in SFFM  table?

Comment: Yes, SEQ is a column in SFFM as well as SCCS

Comment: If you have the identifier names correct, then it execute properly : `MERGE INTO SFFM f 
USING(
SELECT INTSTRTDTE, INTENDDTE, INTSTRTDTE, SEQ
FROM SCCS
) c 
ON (f.SECID = c.SECID AND f.SEQ = c.SEQ)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET f.INTSTRTDTE = c.INTSTRTDTE,
    f.INTENDDTE    = c.INTENDDTE,
    f.EFFDATE      = c.INTSTRTDTE
  WHERE f.SECID    = 'TEST1'
  AND f.AMENDDATE IS NULL;` Can you execute this and check.

Comment: doesn't work. SQL Error: ORA-00904: "F"."SEQ": invalid identifier

Comment: Can you post the output of `desc SFFM;`

Comment: DESC SFFM
Name           Null     Type          
-------------- -------- ------------- 
REC_IDENTITY   NOT NULL NUMBER(18)    
BR             NOT NULL CHAR(2)       
SECID          NOT NULL CHAR(20)      
SEQ            NOT NULL CHAR(4)       
INTSTRTDTE     NOT NULL DATE          
INTENDDTE      NOT NULL DATE          
EFFDATE        NOT NULL DATE          
POSTDATE       NOT NULL DATE          
AMENDDATE               DATE          
AMENDTIME               CHAR(8)       
FACTOR_12               NUMBER(18,12)

Comment: my select subquery from SCCS returns three columns with three diff SEQ but the multi row update on SFFM after select from SCCS fails as it tries to update three rows at the same time. IN SQLSERVER it works.